# Using PHP inside a shortcode inside PHP... syntax issue

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Ok, I'm OK with PHP but not an expert. What's the correct syntax here?

I'm trying to pull in an Advanced Custom Field data INSIDE some PHP, which is INSIDE a shortcode.

I have an ACF field called: the_sub_field("google_doc_key")

```
<div><?php echo do_shortcode("[gdoc key='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"'. the_sub_field("google_doc_key") .'"/edit' gid='0']"); ?></div>
```

Somethings not right here... any help is appreciated.

Comment: The syntax highlighting might give you a hand.

Comment: You need to use `get_sub_field()` in this case.

Comment: php strings never start with a double quote and end with a single quote.

Comment: your ' and " are mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div><?php echo do_shortcode("[gdoc key='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'". the_sub_field("google_doc_key") ."'/edit' gid='0']"); ?></div>
```

Try that, you had the ' and " mixed up just before the_sub_field